# Change permissions of a Windows share from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, permissions, windows

I have a folder on a Windows share, which is exported from a Windows file server. The folder is used to share data with Windows users on my network. I have no problem mounting it, using it or writing to it.

However, sometimes I need to explicitly grant a new user permission to read my files. I usually do it by logging into one of our Windows machines.

Can I change Windows network permissions from Ubuntu?